# storing filename of JavaScript file in database

Tags: json, jquery

I have the JavaScript file name in the database, and I have a jQuery ajax script on the clientside page which returns JSON data containing the JavaScript filenames.

I'm having to do awful stuff like this:

`$( "head" ).append( "<scr" + "ipt type='text/javascript' src='js/" + widget_data.d[i].script + "'></scr" + "ipt>" );`

Is there are recommended/preferred way of dynamically adding scripts to a HTML pages head section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using jQuery, the easiest way is to use `$.getScript()`, like in this example: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-load-javascript-at-runtime-with-jquery/

DOCS: [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: Once you get the script, is it possible to remove it again to prevent it clashing with other scripts when not needed?

Comment: As per docs, the script will be executed immediately. What do you mean "not clashing" by the way? Scripts will clash only if they reference or define the same globals and there are other techniques to avoid that (namespacing for example)

Comment: For example, to avoid a script getting added more than once.

Comment: My only suggestion would be to push the loaded script name into some kind of array and eventually check for duplicates before loading...